# Inserir valor no javascript pegandoo do php-mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Olá, não sou programado, mas estou fazendo um site onde quero colocar um contador para determinar qual será o vencimento do registro do site.
usei o 3D Cube Countdown script, mas gostaria que a data viesses direto do php-mysql para ser automático. veja parte do código

```
jQuery(function($){ // on DOM load

//Eg #1
var mycountdown = new cubecountdown({
    containerid: 'futuredate',
```

> Aqui gostaria de receber o campo data_vencimento do MYSQL

```
targetdate: 'October 17, 2017 11:26:30',
```

> minha dúvida

```
    size: ['10em', '6em'], // specify cube dimensions in "em" only
    unit: ['days']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a consulta / script forem feitos na mesma página você pode passar a string php para javascript da seguinte forma:

```
var minhaVarJS = <?=$MinhaVarPHP?>
```

Antes de passar para Javascript use json_encode() na sua variável PHP.

Se forem feitas em páginas diferentes recomendo o uso de Ajax para recuperar essas informações.

```
$.ajax(function(){
    type: "POST",
    url: "suaURL.php",
    data: 'seu-post',
    success: function(data)
        {
            minhaVar = data;
        }
});
```

E em sua página PHP que irá receber esse post você faz a pesquisa no banco de dados conforme os parâmetros passados em data: 'seu-post', após a pesquisa você da um

```
echo json_encode($minhaVarPHP);
```